# Reading char arrays using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, char

I'm trying to read some `char` arrays from keyboard, but every time the program crashes.

I would like to know how I can comfortably input and store `char` arrays from keyboard.

```
int main()
{

    int i;
    char *days[7];

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", days[i]);
    }


    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", days[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `scanf()` call is wrong. `*days[7]` is an array of pointers to char not an array of strings.

Comment: You need to initialize each pointer first before you attempt writing.

Comment: JackBet, Save time.  Enable all warnings to get rapid feedback on bad code `char *days[7]; ...   scanf("%s", days[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

`char *days[7]` declares an array of pointers. Unless initialized with valid address, they point to invalid memory locations. So, when you want to write to them, they invoke undefined behaviour.

You need to ensure to make them point towards valid memory (locations), before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo declare an aaray of pointer to `char` but those pointers do not reference valid memory.

You need to allocate memory for them:

```
int main(void)
    int i;
    char *days[7];

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        days[i] = malloc(MAXLENGTH);
        scanf("%15s", days[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", days[i]);
        free(days[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or you can

```
int main(void)
{

    int i;
    char days[7][MAXLENGTH];

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        scanf("%15s", days[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", days[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can i also allocate out of the for cycle?
Like 
days = malloc (MAXLENGHT * numberOfArrays *sizeof(char))
?